# InAppBrowser and FileTransfer in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

my `ionic info` of my project is

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.4
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms               : none
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.3.0

System:

    Node       : v6.10.3
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

In my existing project i need to work implement `InAppBrowser` and `FileTransfer` plugin the official document is updated to ionic 3 how can i find plugin related doc for my current version or is there any alternative way to do it.

Comment: I did find https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-site/tree/Hitman666-master/docs/v2/native but not sure how updated that is..you can check other branches in github. But this question will be offtopic as you are askinh for an offsite resource

Comment: @suraj the two plugins i am looking for is not available in that github